# laravel ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after adding SSL

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, ssl

so i am using cloudways with digitalocean and now trying to add letsencrypt into my laravel 5.4 web app...

and according to tech support in cloudways they say i need to modify my .htaccess to be like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

but after that i got

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

what's gone wrong? cloudways tech support can't give any solution either... so i kinda stuck in here

i also do some research before and read that i need to add

```
If(env(' APP_ENV') !== 'local') { $url->forceSchema('https'); }
```

into app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php in boot function to make all request to be https....

but still no luck...

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on` instead of `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https`

Comment: nope.... still not working...

Comment: append a debug param in order to see actual variable content. `... https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ...`

Comment: hmm still not working.... ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so i already got the solution, i forgot that my site also have cloudflare cdn and in crypto part it set SSL to Full mode, just change it to flexible one and everything works great....